# coldfusion jar dependency conflicts

Tags: java, jar, coldfusion

Q: Is there any way to force CF to use a certain set of jar files instead of their default versions?

I am attempting to run/call a 3rd party java application from within a ColdFusion page.  The application has over 150 jar files, some custom and some 3rd party (eg. Apache).

Whether I put all of the new jar files in `/lib`, or use the `application.cfc` to specify the correct class path (below), or use in the cfide settings, I get dependency conflicts.

`this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["/Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/norconex_lib/"], loadColdFusionClassPath = false, reloadOnChange = false ,watchInterval=30};`

The immediate error message complains that `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`. But i'm not sure what else lies in store for me even if I whack that mole.

I don't see anything like this in the posts so I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like classic jar version conflict. Despite using javaSettings it can still happen when multiple versions of the same jar are in the class path. Especially ones used by the CF engine. CF uses a lot of open source libs.  Xerces is one. You can put jars in  `JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` but that may break things if CF requires a different version.  Not pretty, but only thing I can suggest is check the `[cf_root}/lib` directory for overlaps like Xerces, omit those jars from your `loadPaths` and try again.  Don't forget to reload the app or it won't change.

Comment: There a plenty of versions of `xerces` around. One does nor work well with the others. Leave `xml-apis` out and there's an exception (class not found). Take any version and there's the said conflict. Likely because `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl` is loaded via a different classloader than `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`

Comment: @user2258677.. I am also facing same situation but conflict is with Java.mail. My jar has javax.mail and ColdFusion in built also has javax.mail . And hence conflicts happening. Please let me know if you get any resolutions for this issue?